# How to resize a figure inside /Figure caption in Latex

Tags: floats, ieeetran, overleaf, resize

I am trying to adapt my paper into IEEE Access template in Overleaf. According to the documentation I have to define a figure by using **\Figure** tag instead of using **\begin{figure}** tag. Here is the example from IEEE Access template in below:

```
\Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt){fig1.png}
{Magnetization as a function of applied field.
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption.\label{fig1}}
```

However if I use this for my figure, the size exceeds the width in text block. And I couldn't find how to use it. On the other hand If I use \begin{figure} tag the caption is not the same as it supposed to be.

Comment: Hi there! This is Tom from Overleaf Support Team. Can you please try `\Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt)[width=0.9\linewidth]{fig1.png}
{Caption}`? I'm not sure if it's documented anywhere, but it should work.

Comment: Yes this solution worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution which is answered by Tom (@yo') from Overleaf Team in below:

```
   \Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt)[width=0.9\linewidth] 
    {fig1.png} {Caption}
```